# I cant save some facebook images to my server as it does not understand the file

Tags: php, imagick, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using the facebook graph api and it was working well until I realised that some of the jpg files have a query string at the end that is making them unusable.

e.g.
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/487872_451835128174833_1613257199_n.jpg?oh=621bed79f5436e81c3e219c86db8f0d9&oe=560F3D0D

I have tried stripping off everything after `.jpg` in the hope that it would still load the image but unfortunately it doesnt.

In the following code take the `$facebook_image_url` to be the one above. This works fine when the url ends in `.jpg` but fails on the above. As a note, I am converting the name to a random number

```
        $File_Name          = $facebook_image_url;
        $File_Ext           = '.jpg'; 
        $Random_Number      = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to be added to name.
        $NewFileName        = $Random_Number.$File_Ext; //new file name


        $local_file = $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName;
        $remote_file = $File_Name;
        $ch = curl_init();
        $fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
        $ch = curl_init($remote_file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);

        $image = new Imagick(DIR_TEMPORARY_IMAGES.$NewFileName);
```

The error Im getting is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Not a
>   JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x21  `/mysite/temp-images/1849974705.jpg'
>   @ jpeg.c/EmitMessage/232'

I can confirm the image isnt saving as a proper jpg, just a small 3KB file with the name 1849974705.jpg (or other random numbers)

Is there either

A: A way of getting those images from facebook as raw jpg

or

B: A way of converting them succesfully to jpgs

Comment: `0x3c 0x21` -> `<!`, which means you probably retrieved an html or xml document. never assume that your web request will produce the exact thing you asked for. ALWAYS check for failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise. and of course you're always going to get "xxx.jpg", because that's what you told curl to write the file out to. What goes INTO that file doesn't HAVE to be jpeg data. it'll be whatever facebook sent in response to your request.

Comment: Try saving the file instead of passing it to imagick and see what it contains.

Comment: you're right, its html, i was hoping it would be html that contains a url to the image but unforunately it just contains the html of a broken facebook image... e.g. https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/251456_10152100600625545_305713343_n.jpg

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Well to be honest I assumed if they are supplying urls to their images via an API that they know people may have to do SOME server work on them surely, especially considering only some of the images seem to be like that , others are fine and end in jpg and work perfectly. Perhaps the more important question I should be asking is whats the difference between the two and how do i target the "public" ones so to speak

Comment: just to clarify I retrieved those images via their graph API

Comment: OK, just making sure you're doing things legally. In that case, try setting a user agent and referrer in your curl request.

Comment: ah I see, i appreciate that, I set them and this time they saved a file but when i went to check it it was simply empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always download the image using `file_get_contents()`

This code works for me...

```
file_put_contents("image.jpg", file_get_contents("https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/522827_10152235166655545_26514444_n.jpg?oh=1d52a86082c7904da8f12920e28d3687&oe=5659D5BB"));
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, Im unsure why cURL wouldnt work but cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just because something has .jpg in the URI doesn't mean it's an image.

Getting that URL via wget gives the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="facebook">
  <head>
    <title>Facebook | Error</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <style>
    ....
    ....
```

i.e. it's not an image, exactly as the error message is telling you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see that now that its html that Im saving. Im wondering might you have any clue as to how to obtain the image itself? I have been stuck for 2 days on this issue now and cant figure it out

Comment: Ive given this the correct answer as it answers the question being asked above