# How do I obtain the image from this Facebook url and save it to my server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am using the facebook graph API and cURL to save images.

Some urls for the image that the API serve up are fine and work perfectly with the code below, but others are not actual image files, e.g.

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/10173560_10154038367445545_5235985017751927246_n.jpg?oh=dea01d8125a54a6bbcba7d5fe5fb795c&oe=564C01E1

So the following does not work as the response I receive is html...

```
        $url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/10173560_10154038367445545_5235985017751927246_n.jpg?oh=dea01d8125a54a6bbcba7d5fe5fb795c&oe=564C01E1";
        $local_file = $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName;
        $remote_file = $url;
        $ch = curl_init();
        $fp = fopen ($local_file, 'w+');
        $ch = curl_init($remote_file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572292/i-cant-save-some-facebook-images-to-my-server-as-it-does-not-understand-the-file) but this really only answers the question of what was happening to the image.

EDIT: This question is different from the one referenced because in this I am asking to actually obtain the image from the url, whereas in the other one I was unsure why I wasnt seeing an image saving.

I now have an answer which I believe could help someone else, I will remove the below and add it as answer if its re-opened.

```
file_put_contents("image.jpg", file_get_contents("https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/522827_10152235166655545_26514444_n.jpg?oh=1d52a86082c7904da8f12920e28d3687&oe=5659D5BB"));
```

Comment: That is still the same problem, and basically the same question.

Comment: Its the same problem but I realised the main question was answered, which was "why arent my images working". They are not working because they are simply not images. My question here is "how do I get those images". I feel its a different question and could throw someone off if they read the previous question. I will edit though for clarity