# Most efficient way of sending very large base64 data over ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to send a giant string over ajax to my server for php to handle it.

There is no point in pasting the base64 data but we are talking high quality images 2000 * 2000 px in size.

The way Im doing it at the moment doesnt work well unless Im on a very fast internet connection, sometimes it takes so long it times out. Im wondering is there a better way I could do it?

```
convertImgToBase64(imageUrl, function(base64Img){
    console.log(base64Img);

    //alert(base64Img);
           $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/image_upload',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            img : base64Img,
        },
        success: function(json) {
         //stuff

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't use base64 for such large images. base64 is useful for some encodings and to store small images (icon size) in CSS to reduce the number of requests and the overhead that comes with those requests. Sending such large chunks of data in base64 is crazy.

Comment: Unfortunately Ive no other way of sending the image as I convert it to that from a facebook image url and my php cannot read the url using cURL, see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593280/how-do-i-obtain-the-image-from-this-facebok-url-to-save-to-my-server to explain more

Comment: perhaps if there was a way of convertiing it before sending that could work